# Are there any tools for generating a WADL file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-4.0, wadl

I've built a RESTful web service (I'm using asp.net 4, MVC 2) and I want to expose a WADL. Are there any tools built in or otherwise that I can use to build it? I'm not looking (yet) to generate classes to consume it I'm looking strictly for something that can generate the WADL file itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [REST Describe & Compile](http://tomayac.de/rest-describe/latest/RestDescribe.html) should do the trick.

> On the WADL developer site Marc Hadley
>   maintains a command line tool named
>   WADL2Java. The ambitious goal of REST
>   Describe & Compile is to provide sort
>   of WADL2Anything. So what REST
>   Describe & Compile does is that it:
>
> - **Generates new WADL files in a completely interactive way.**
> - Lets you upload and edit existing WADL files.
> - Allows you to compile WADL files to source code in various programming
>     languages.

Comment: That site of REST Describe & Compile is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is a maven plugin called `maven-wadl-plugin` by the jersey folks that does the trick.

Check the answers in this other question: [WADL Generation Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486835/wadl-generation-tool/14742322#14742322) .

--A