# WADL Generation Tool

Tags: java, rest, soapui, wadl

Is there a tool which takes a Java File what describes a REST service as a parameter and generates a wadl file out of that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same problem: was using RESTeasy and wanted to find a way to generate the WADL automatically.

Did some research and came to the solution below.

## 1. Add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-wadl-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>${javadoc-phase}</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <wadlFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.wadl
            </wadlFile>
            <formatWadlFile>true</formatWadlFile>
            <baseUri>http://example.com:8080/rest</baseUri>
            <packagesResourceConfig>
                <param>com.example.rs.resource</param>
            </packagesResourceConfig>
            <wadlGenerators>
                <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                    <className>com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc
                    </className>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>applicationDocsFile</name>
                            <value>${basedir}/src/main/doc/application-doc.xml</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </wadlGeneratorDescription>
                <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                    <className>com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport
                    </className>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>grammarsFile</name>
                            <value>${basedir}/src/main/doc/application-grammars.xml</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </wadlGeneratorDescription>
            </wadlGenerators>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Pay attention to the `buildUri` and `packagesResourceConfig` elements. You have to change them to reflect your project's configuration. You may also want to change the plugin's version (I used 1.17).

## 2. Create a /doc folder and add some files.

Create the `src/main/doc/` folder and create the two files below.

File: **application-doc.xml**

Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<applicationDocs targetNamespace="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
    <doc xml:lang="en" title="A message in the WADL">This is added to the start of the generated application.wadl</doc>
</applicationDocs>
```

File: **application-grammars.xml**

Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<grammars xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" />
```

## 3. Run the maven command.

Go to the project folder and run the following command:

```
$ mvn compile com.sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:generate
```

The files `\target\classes\application.wadl` (the WADL itself) and `\target\classes\xsd0.xsd`  (the schema of the resources - it's used by the application.wadl) should be generated.

Edit and use them as you wish.

PS.: Bear in mind that this is a very simple use of the maven-wadl-plugin. It can do a lot more. To know it better, please refer to the zip file mentioned in the other answer (by Pavel Bucek).

Comment: Documentation is really lacking. Is the `packagesResourceConfig` supposed to the location of the classes with the actual endpoints?

Comment: @jiggy `packagesResourceConfig` is the java package where your resources (services) classes are located.

Comment: How does the xsd get generated? None is being produced.

Comment: Thanks for the well-documented tip on creating a WADL.  I was having an issue trying to run the NetBeans sample 'CustomerDB' when deploying to TomEE Plume 7.0.4 since that setup would not auto-generate the WADL (ergo: missing WADL.)  Off to fixing the next issue outside of WADL.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, please see gerenate-wadl [1] sample from Jersey samples (look for maven-wadl-plugin).

[1] http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/jersey/samples/generate-wadl/1.12/generate-wadl-1.12-project.zip