# How can I generate WADL for REST services

Tags: java, rest, testing, jax-rs, wadl

I have a web application providing more than 30 REST services (using Jersey) to clients. Is it possible to automatically create a WADL document for my application?

I need this, so that I can have it configured in SoapUI for testing various scenarios and save it for later use.

Comment: Jersey will do that too. https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/WADL

Comment: if you are using jersey then url to wadl would be    http://localhost:8080/applicationname/application.wadl

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using Jersey then url to wadl would be something like

`http://localhost:8080/applicationname/application.wadl`

You may need to add the resource base into the url e.g.

`http://localhost:8080/applicationname/resources/application.wadl`

Comment: In jersy who will create this WADL, if it is automatically generated then what environment and API needed for this ?

Comment: I think it needs to be specified as a parameter to your build system (e.g. in the pom.xml file for Maven). https://stackoverflow.com/a/14742322/714112

Answer (score 9):

```
http://{host}:{port}/{context_root}/{resource}/application.wadl
```

substitute values for `host`, `port`, `context root` and `resource`.

Answer (score 7):

In the past I've used [Enunciate](http://enunciate.webcohesion.com/) ([GitHub repository](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate)).

It's a build-time tool that generates Interface Definition Documents (WADL, WSDL, etc) automatically for you. It's really easy to integrate it in your Maven build.

Comment: Yes, and it also integrates with Spring which separate well the processing layer (@Service) from the exposition layer (REST, SOAP). The enunciate documentation of the service is very well generated.

Comment: The codehaus link is dead. The code is on GitHub https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate and it links to the site http://enunciate.webcohesion.com/