# Jersey : Generating a wadl give me No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, wadl

I read a couple if thing on the net but it's like greek to me.
eg :
[jackson disable fail_on_empty_beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261456/jackson-disable-fail-on-empty-beans)
Nothing seems to be related to a non wadl generation trouble.

I do have a rest service up and running locally, installed on a Tomcat server.
As the service is growing up, i decided to use Jersey ability to get a wadl.

But when i tried to call the following adress , i've got an error

```
http://localhost:9090/android-rest-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT/application.wadl
```

( tried also on server )

I'm quite afraid of integrating wrapper especially as the rest is working fine.

May someone kindly explain how i can do to get my wadl generated ?

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:114)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:809)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:684)
    at com.myc.android.rest.util.LoggingResponseFilter.filter(LoggingResponseFilter.java:27)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:379)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:371)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:983)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:361)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>PLRWA</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myc.android.rest.service.RegisterApplication</param-value>         
        </init-param>       
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>Database resource for RS </description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/restDemoDBOracle</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>     
</web-app>
```

My POM file as follow

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.myc</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>DemoRestWS</name>
    <description>REST web services monté avec spring, jersey et jpa2/hibernate pour android</description>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.7.Final</hibernate.version>
        <jetty.version>9.2.0.RC0</jetty.version> <!-- Adapt this to a version found on http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/ -->
        <logback.version>1.1.1</logback.version>
        <jcloverslf4j.version>1.7.6</jcloverslf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- Jersey-Spring http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-spring3/2.4.1 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
            </exclusions>           
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Oracle JDBC connector -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
              <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- tomcat jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.35</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ******* JPA/Hibernate ******** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20140107</version>
</dependency>


        <!-- testing -->
        <!-- Jersey-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>            
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Groovy because of classpath issue -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-external</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LogBack dependencies --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>                                    
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>                
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>     
            <version>${jcloverslf4j.version}</version>  
        </dependency>               
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jettyConfig>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/jetty9.xml</jettyConfig>
                    <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                    <stopWait>5</stopWait>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <scanTargets>
                        <scanTarget>${project.basedir}/src/main</scanTarget>
                        <scanTarget>${project.basedir}/src/test</scanTarget>
                    </scanTargets>
                    <contextXml>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/jetty-context.xml</contextXml>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <!--<dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.27</version>
                    </dependency>
                    -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>14</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run-exploded</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Added :** Service and others

```
@Component
@Path("/kit")
public class KitRestService {

    @Autowired
    private KitDao kitDao;

    /************************************ READ ************************************/

    @GET
    @Path("/getMagasinKit")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response getMagasinKit(@QueryParam("kit") Integer kit,@QueryParam("sitegeo") String sitegeo) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        List<String> magasinkit= kitDao.getMagasinKit(kit, sitegeo);
        return Response.ok(magasinkit).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
    }
}
```

**KitDaoJPA2Impl**  ( KitDao is a public interface )

```
public class KitDaoJPA2Impl implements KitDao {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KitDaoJPA2Impl.class);

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="sitesOracle")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    // Kit entete
    public List<KitEntete> getKitEntete(String metier, String sitegeo, String cptdossier, Integer numligne) {

        String qlString = "SELECT k "+
        "FROM KitEntete k "+
        "WHERE k.ficheMetier = ?1 and k.ficheSitegeo = ?2 and k.ficheDossier = ?3 and k.ficheLigne = ?4";
        TypedQuery<KitEntete> query = entityManager.createQuery(qlString, KitEntete.class); 
        query.setParameter(1, metier);
        query.setParameter(2, sitegeo);
        query.setParameter(3, cptdossier);
        query.setParameter(4, numligne);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

KitEntete

```
public class KitEntete extends BaseKitEntete {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/*[CONSTRUCTOR MARKER BEGIN]*/
    public KitEntete () {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for primary key
     */
    public KitEntete (java.lang.Integer id) {
        super(id);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for required fields
     */
    public KitEntete (
        java.lang.Integer id,
        java.lang.Integer statut) {

        super (
            id,
            statut);
    }

/*[CONSTRUCTOR MARKER END]*/


}
```

BaseKitEntete

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public abstract class BaseKitEntete  implements Serializable {

    public static String REF = "KitEntete";
    public static String PROP_PRODUIT = "produit";
    public static String PROP_FICHE_SITEGEO = "ficheSitegeo";
    public static String PROP_DATEMOD = "datemod";
    public static String PROP_BL_METIER = "blMetier";
    public static String PROP_FICHE_DOSSIER = "ficheDossier";
    public static String PROP_UTILCRE = "utilcre";
    public static String PROP_BL_NUMBL = "blNumbl";
    public static String PROP_BL_SITEGEO = "blSitegeo";
    public static String PROP_BON_LIV_RETOUR = "bonLivRetour";
    public static String PROP_DATECRE = "datecre";
    public static String PROP_TYPE_KIT = "type_kit";
    public static String PROP_TYPE_CARTE = "type_carte";
    public static String PROP_FICHE_LIGNE = "ficheLigne";
    public static String PROP_STATUT = "statut";
    public static String PROP_UTILMOD = "utilmod";
    public static String PROP_FICHE_METIER = "ficheMetier";
    public static String PROP_ID = "id";


    // constructors
    public BaseKitEntete () {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for primary key
     */
    public BaseKitEntete (java.lang.Integer id) {
        this.setId(id);
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for required fields
     */
    public BaseKitEntete (
        java.lang.Integer id,
        java.lang.Integer statut) {

        this.setId(id);
        this.setStatut(statut);
        initialize();
    }

    protected void initialize () {}



    private int hashCode = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    // primary key
    private java.lang.Integer id;

    // fields
    private java.lang.Integer statut;
    private java.lang.String blMetier;
    private java.lang.String blSitegeo;
    private java.lang.String blNumbl;
    private java.lang.String ficheMetier;
    private java.lang.String ficheSitegeo;
    private java.lang.String ficheDossier;
    private java.lang.Integer ficheLigne;
    private java.lang.String utilcre;
    private java.util.Date datecre;
    private java.lang.String utilmod;
    private java.util.Date datemod;
    private java.lang.Integer type_kit;
    private java.lang.Integer type_carte;
    private java.lang.String bonLivRetour;


    // collections
    private java.util.Set<com.myc.android.rest.entities.KitLigne> kitLigne;



    /**
     * Return the unique identifier of this class
     * @hibernate.id
     *  generator-class="sequence"
     *  column="ID"
     */
    public java.lang.Integer getId () {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Set the unique identifier of this class
     * @param id the new ID
     */
    public void setId (java.lang.Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.hashCode = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }




    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: STATUT
     */
    public java.lang.Integer getStatut () {
        return statut;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: STATUT
     * @param statut the STATUT value
     */
    public void setStatut (java.lang.Integer statut) {
        this.statut = statut;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: BL_METIER
     */
    public java.lang.String getBlMetier () {
        return blMetier;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: BL_METIER
     * @param blMetier the BL_METIER value
     */
    public void setBlMetier (java.lang.String blMetier) {
        this.blMetier = blMetier;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: BL_SITEGEO
     */
    public java.lang.String getBlSitegeo () {
        return blSitegeo;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: BL_SITEGEO
     * @param blSitegeo the BL_SITEGEO value
     */
    public void setBlSitegeo (java.lang.String blSitegeo) {
        this.blSitegeo = blSitegeo;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: BL_NUMBL
     */
    public java.lang.String getBlNumbl () {
        return blNumbl;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: BL_NUMBL
     * @param blNumbl the BL_NUMBL value
     */
    public void setBlNumbl (java.lang.String blNumbl) {
        this.blNumbl = blNumbl;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: FICHE_METIER
     */
    public java.lang.String getFicheMetier () {
        return ficheMetier;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: FICHE_METIER
     * @param ficheMetier the FICHE_METIER value
     */
    public void setFicheMetier (java.lang.String ficheMetier) {
        this.ficheMetier = ficheMetier;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: FICHE_SITEGEO
     */
    public java.lang.String getFicheSitegeo () {
        return ficheSitegeo;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: FICHE_SITEGEO
     * @param ficheSitegeo the FICHE_SITEGEO value
     */
    public void setFicheSitegeo (java.lang.String ficheSitegeo) {
        this.ficheSitegeo = ficheSitegeo;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: FICHE_CPTDOSSIER
     */
    public java.lang.String getFicheDossier () {
        return ficheDossier;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: FICHE_CPTDOSSIER
     * @param ficheDossier the FICHE_CPTDOSSIER value
     */
    public void setFicheDossier (java.lang.String ficheDossier) {
        this.ficheDossier = ficheDossier;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: FICHE_NUMLIGNE
     */
    public java.lang.Integer getFicheLigne () {
        return ficheLigne;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: FICHE_NUMLIGNE
     * @param ficheLigne the FICHE_NUMLIGNE value
     */
    public void setFicheLigne (java.lang.Integer ficheLigne) {
        this.ficheLigne = ficheLigne;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: UTILCRE
     */
    public java.lang.String getUtilcre () {
        return utilcre;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: UTILCRE
     * @param utilcre the UTILCRE value
     */
    public void setUtilcre (java.lang.String utilcre) {
        this.utilcre = utilcre;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: DATECRE
     */
    public java.util.Date getDatecre () {
        return datecre;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: DATECRE
     * @param datecre the DATECRE value
     */
    public void setDatecre (java.util.Date datecre) {
        this.datecre = datecre;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: UTILMOD
     */
    public java.lang.String getUtilmod () {
        return utilmod;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: UTILMOD
     * @param utilmod the UTILMOD value
     */
    public void setUtilmod (java.lang.String utilmod) {
        this.utilmod = utilmod;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: DATEMOD
     */
    public java.util.Date getDatemod () {
        return datemod;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: DATEMOD
     * @param datemod the DATEMOD value
     */
    public void setDatemod (java.util.Date datemod) {
        this.datemod = datemod;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: TYPE_KIT
     */
    public java.lang.Integer getType_kit () {
        return type_kit;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: TYPE_KIT
     * @param type_kit the TYPE_KIT value
     */
    public void setType_kit (java.lang.Integer type_kit) {
        this.type_kit = type_kit;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: TYPE_CARTE
     */
    public java.lang.Integer getType_carte () {
        return type_carte;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: TYPE_CARTE
     * @param type_carte the TYPE_CARTE value
     */
    public void setType_carte (java.lang.Integer type_carte) {
        this.type_carte = type_carte;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: BON_LIV_RETOUR
     */
    public java.lang.String getBonLivRetour () {
        return bonLivRetour;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: BON_LIV_RETOUR
     * @param bonLivRetour the BON_LIV_RETOUR value
     */
    public void setBonLivRetour (java.lang.String bonLivRetour) {
        this.bonLivRetour = bonLivRetour;
    }



    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: NUMPRO

    public com.myc.android.rest.entities.References getProduit () {
        return produit;
    }

    public void setProduit (com.myc.android.rest.entities.References produit) {
        this.produit = produit;
    }

 */

    /**
     * Return the value associated with the column: kitLigne
     */
    public java.util.Set<com.myc.android.rest.entities.KitLigne> getKitLigne () {
        return kitLigne;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value related to the column: kitLigne
     * @param kitLigne the kitLigne value
     */
    public void setKitLigne (java.util.Set<com.myc.android.rest.entities.KitLigne> kitLigne) {
        this.kitLigne = kitLigne;
    }

    public void addTokitLigne (com.myc.android.rest.entities.KitLigne kitLigne) {
        if (null == getKitLigne()) setKitLigne(new java.util.TreeSet<com.myc.android.rest.entities.KitLigne>());
        getKitLigne().add(kitLigne);
    }




    public boolean equals (Object obj) {
        if (null == obj) return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof com.myc.android.rest.entities.KitEntete)) return false;
        else {
            com.myc.android.rest.entities.KitEntete kitEntete = (com.myc.android.rest.entities.KitEntete) obj;
            if (null == this.getId() || null == kitEntete.getId()) return false;
            else return (this.getId().equals(kitEntete.getId()));
        }
    }

    public int hashCode () {
        if (Integer.MIN_VALUE == this.hashCode) {
            if (null == this.getId()) return super.hashCode();
            else {
                String hashStr = this.getClass().getName() + ":" + this.getId().hashCode();
                this.hashCode = hashStr.hashCode();
            }
        }
        return this.hashCode;
    }


    public String toString () {
        return super.toString();
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you  share POJO on which you perform serialization process?

Comment: I added a service as well. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: 1. Tried to add getters and setters within Services classes. No Effects.

Comment: 2. Did follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486835/wadl-generation-tool#answer-14742322

Wadl is generating fine.

Comment: I'll also generate wadl description for restful services those I use.