# Error wher generating wadl by maven-wadl-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jersey, wadl

I am trying to generate WADL using maven-wadl-plugin by this tutorial [WADL Generation Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486835/wadl-generation-tool). But i always get error below. Can someone tell me where problem is because i cant see it. Added pom.xml just for sure.

Here is following error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AMS Airlines 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-wadl-plugin:1.18.1:generate (default-cli) @ ams-airlines ---
[INFO] Loading wadlGenerator com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc
[INFO] Loading wadlGenerator com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport
Říj 26, 2014 12:55:59 DOP. com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory createParserFactory
SEVERE: null
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.setFeature(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParserImpl(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory.createParserFactory(XmlFactory.java:114)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.getXMLReader(UnmarshallerImpl.java:139)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc.init(WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport.init(WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport.java:150)
at com.sun.jersey.wadl.GenerateWadlMojo.executeWithClasspath(GenerateWadlMojo.java:156)
at com.sun.jersey.wadl.AbstractMojoProjectClasspathSupport.execute(AbstractMojoProjectClasspathSupport.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

[ERROR] 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory.createParserFactory(XmlFactory.java:121)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.getXMLReader(UnmarshallerImpl.java:139)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc.init(WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport.init(WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport.java:150)
at com.sun.jersey.wadl.GenerateWadlMojo.executeWithClasspath(GenerateWadlMojo.java:156)
at com.sun.jersey.wadl.AbstractMojoProjectClasspathSupport.execute(AbstractMojoProjectClasspathSupport.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.setFeature(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParserImpl(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory.createParserFactory(XmlFactory.java:114)
... 36 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.431 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-10-26T00:55:59+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.sun.jersey.contribs:maven-wadl-plugin:1.18.1:generate (default-cli) on project ams-airlines: Could not write wadl file: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing ->     [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>au.com.playground</groupId>
<artifactId>ams-airlines</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>AMS Airlines</name>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.5.1</jersey.version>
    <!--<genson.version>0.98</genson.version>-->
    <eclipselink.version>2.5.2-M1</eclipselink.version>
    <derby.version>10.10.1.1</derby.version>
    <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
    <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>${derby.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>jrws</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-wadl-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>${javadoc-phase}</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <wadlFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.wadl
                </wadlFile>
                <formatWadlFile>true</formatWadlFile>
                <baseUri>http://localhost:8080/ams-airlines/rest/</baseUri>
                <packagesResourceConfig>
                    <param>resource</param>
                </packagesResourceConfig>
                <wadlGenerators>
                    <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                        <className>com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc
                        </className>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>applicationDocsFile</name>
                                <value>${basedir}/src/main/doc/application-doc.xml</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </wadlGeneratorDescription>
                    <wadlGeneratorDescription>
                        <className>com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport
                        </className>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>grammarsFile</name>
                                <value>${basedir}/src/main/doc/application-grammars.xml</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </wadlGeneratorDescription>
                </wadlGenerators>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
</plugins>

</build>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrong java JDK. It needs Java JDK 1.7 and i had 1.8.

Comment: Not really a correct solution to the issue, it's like fixing a diplomatic concern with an atomic bomb.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem as well. For me stepping down to Java 7 was not an option though. After some research I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27949008/5039093) to a similar problem not involving wadl files. The modified solution is to add the mentioned dependency to the maven-wadl-plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-wadl-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: NB: be careful to add the dependencies right before the closing plugin tag. At first I put it before the closing configuration tag and maven didn't warn me or anything!